# jQuery - Call one function by hover, then call another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, callback, jquery-callback

So I have a submenu that loads content when a main nav button is hovered over. And while that content is loading I want to display a loading graphic.

The problem is I can't get both functions working together.

1st function - load submenu content (page.php)

2nd function - when page.php is loaded, hide loading graphic

```
<script>
function functionOne() {
jQuery.get('page.php', function(data) { jQuery('.class').html(data); })
}

function functionTwo() {
  jQuery("#loading").hide();    
};

jQuery(".dropdownhover").one('mouseenter', functionOne.done( functionTwo ););
</script>

<a class="dropdownhover">Button</a>
<div id="loading"></div>
```

With the above code, neither function works. If I call just the first function like this: `jQuery(".dropdownhover").one('mouseenter', functionOne );` that works fine. But I of course need to call both, one after the other. Am I just writing the last line of the script wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your requirement, the syntax that you have used is completely wrong, there is no such function `done` available in Function's prototype.

You can achieve that by just writing,

```
function functionOne() {
 jQuery.get('page.php', function(data) { 
   jQuery('.class').html(data); 
   functionTwo(); 
 });
}

function functionTwo() {
  jQuery("#loading").hide();    
};

jQuery(".dropdownhover").one('mouseenter', functionOne);
```

Comment: @SLePort It was OP's code and OP didn't complain anything like, event is triggering for a single time. So I guess that the code was intentional.

Comment: Well that was a lot easier than I thought. This works great thank you. And yes the `.one` was intentional, just need it once.

Comment: @user1610904 Glad to help! :)